# CodeIgniter Form Validation Class - Handling errors

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

So I have made a form with CodeIgniter and it does uses CodeIgniter's form validation
class to validate input fields. I have a total of 6 input fields which all are
required fields.

I would like to show the same error of "This field is required" even 
if there are multiple empty fields, but right now it will show the error message for each
of the fields. So if I leave every field empty, it will echo the same message 6 times.

I won't paste any code here since I know how to use the actual validation class, just 
don't know how to implement it in a way as said above.

Thanks in advance!

E: Now comes another problem, it doesn't show any errors, in fact the whole method will fail right after it's checking if the "add_user" button is submitted. I'm 100% sure that the name of my submit button is "add_user".

Sorry about bad indenting, I'll never learn how to use StackOverflow's indenting.

Here's my controller for adding a user:

```
<?php

    class Users extends CI_Controller {


    public function add_user() 
    {   



        if($this->input->post('add_user'))
        {   

            $this->load->model('subject');

            $data['subjects'] = $this->subject->get_all_subjects();
            $data['schools'] = $this->subject->get_all_schools();


            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_name', 'Etunimi', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('l_name', 'Sukunimi', 'min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Sähköpostiosoite', 'matches[email_confirm]|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_confirm', 'Sähköpostiosoite', 'valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Puhelinnumero', 'min_length[7]|max_length[10]');

            if($this->input->post('user_type') == "moderator")
            {   
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('school', 'Koulutalo', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Laji', 'required');

            }

            $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Täyttämättömiä kenttiä');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s - kentässä on liian vähän merkkejä');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'Sähköpostit eivät täsmää');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s on jo rekisteröity');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {

            $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array() )));
                return false;

            }


            $first_part_username = substr($this->input->post('f_name'), 0, 2);
            $second_part_username = substr($this->input->post('l_name'), 0, 3);

            $first_part_username = strtolower($first_part_username);
            $second_part_username = strtolower($second_part_username);

            $this->load->helper('string');

            $random_number = random_string('numeric', 4);

            $username = $first_part_username . $second_part_username .$random_number;


                $password = random_string('alnum', 8);

                $this->load->model('user');

                $name = ucfirst($this->input->post('f_name')). " " .ucfirst($this->input->post('l_name'));

                $data = array (
                'name'      => $name,
                'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
                'username'  => $username,
                'password'  => $this->phpass->hash($password),
                'user_type'     => $this->input->post('user_type'),
                'phone_number'  => $this->input->post('phone_number'),
                'subject_id'    => !($this->input->post('subject')) ? null : $this->input->post('subject'),
'school_id' => !($this->input->post('school')) ? null : $this->input->post('school')
                    );


            $this->user->add_user($data);
        $this->load->library('email');

            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));  
            $this->email->subject('test test');
            $this->email->message('Test');

            if($this->email->send()) {

                $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result'=>1, 'msg' => 'Uusi käyttäjä lisätty')));
            }
        }

            /* It will echo out this one which is viewable from developer tab right after the form is submitted */

            $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result'=>1, 'msg' => 'Form not submitted')));
    }
}
?>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#add_user_form").on('submit', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

                $("#loading_spinner").show();
                var from = $(this);

                $.ajax({

                    url: from.attr('action'),
                    type: from.attr('method'),
                    data: $(from).serialize(),
                    }).done(function(data) {



                    if(data.result == 0) {

                        $("#forgot-pass-success").hide();
                        $("#forgot-pass-error").show();
                        $("#forgot-pass-error").fadeIn(1000).html("<p>" + data.error + "</p>");

                      }

                    if(data.result == 1) {

                        $("#forgot-pass-error").hide();
                        $("#forgot-pass-success").show();
                        $("#forgot-pass-success").fadeIn(1000).html("<p>" + data.msg + "</p>");
                      }

                   $("#loading_spinner").hide(); 

                }, 'json');

            return false;

        });
});
```

Comment: You have to loop over the array sent from PHP in your javascript to display each error btw. I'm looking at your code still.

Comment: $this->load->library('form_validation'); only has to be loaded once in that function to work for the entire function. So you can remove the duplicates.

Comment: Done those.. Now it will echo out the "Form was not submitted" as JSON every time. So basically the AJAX part is working when it comes to getting those JSON's.

Comment: Yes now change this $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array() ))); TO $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result'=>1, 'msg' => $this->form_validation->error_array()))); so it matches your scheme

Comment: You are correct about the JSON and the one added needed to change to msg so we could see it in your output.

Comment: var output = '<ul>';
                    for (var key in o.error) {
                        var value = o.error[key];
                        output += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                    }
                    output += '</ul>';
                    $("#register_form_error").html(output); You have to loop your output for the errors in order to see them all. This is the example loop I posted for you.

Comment: Well, of course.. I already did that. The problem is that the output is always "Form was not submitted", no matter what I do.

Comment: right before this line $first_part_username = substr($this->input->post('f_name'), 0, 2); please add echo validation_errors; or $this->validation_errors; and die;It's very late for me so I'm losing steam :/

Comment: Well now I removed the ajax part to check if it's still working and now I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::error_array()

Comment: I will come back to this tomorrow I have to part for the night, I'll have a fresh start on this tomorrow.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Sähköpostiosoite', 'matches[email_confirm]|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email'); Please make sure that you are using is_unique[users.email] is a database/table and that you load the appropriate model for this or you need to remove it from the rule. I think this may be causing your issue right now.

Comment: I'm really going now but I just had to have one more look before bed, fix that and post the status and I will help you with this tomorrow.

Comment: Got it work man.. The problem was with if($this->input->post("submit_user"). After I changed that to if($_POST) it started to work.. Thank you, you we're a big help! Cheers mate and happy easter to you :)

Comment: So my answer was correct we just needed to fix that $_POST sweet!(:

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that returns the errors in a JSON string to process with jQuery, you have to load the form validation helper.

Load the library:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

        /* Outputto Json Format */
        $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
        /* Validate Form Data */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[16]|is_unique[user.login]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_lenght[6]|max_length[16]|matches[confirm_password]');
        /* Custom Messages */
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You must enter a %s.');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'That %s is already in use, please try again.');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'You must enter a vaild email address.');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()]));
            return false;
        }

$login = $this->input->post('login');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $confirm_password = $this->input->post('comfirm_password');

        $user_id = // DO YOUR QUERY HERE


        if($user_id)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(['user_id' => $user_id]);
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 1]));
            return false;
        }
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => 'User not created.']));
```

EDIT:
Sorry I'm using a custom library to extend the form_validation so I can create arrays to return. Just make sure you save this in your library files as my_form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function error_array()
    {
        if(count($this->_error_array > 0))
        {
            return $this->_error_array;
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

**EDIT: Example of dealing with this data in jQuery**

```
<!-- Javascript POST -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // You need to create a div called #register_form_error
        $("#register_form_error").hide();
        // Your register form would go here in place of #regiser_form
        $("#register_form").submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var postData = $(this).serialize();

            $.post(url, postData, function(o) { 
                if (o.result == 1) {
                    // If the registration was successful where to go.
                    window.location.href = '<?=site_url('where to go')?>';
                } else {
                    // This is where all of the form errors will be displayed
                    $("#register_form_error").show();
                    var output = '<ul>';
                    for (var key in o.error) {
                        var value = o.error[key];
                        output += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                    }
                    output += '</ul>';
                    $("#register_form_error").html(output);
                }
            }, 'json');

        });

    });
</script>
```

Lastly:

```
if($this->input->post('add_user'))
```

Shoud be:

```
if($this->input->post('$_POST'))
```

That way you get the entire post array.

Comment: $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()])); <- this line broke's my code so there has to be some sort of error or typo, but I can't figure it out

Comment: @B_CooperA sorry I forgot I extended the default form_validation, I edited my post so you could use it as well.

Comment: I'm confused. I've done everything you mentioned above, but the code is still broken (just getting a blank page). I've copied your extended library, placed it in application/libraries folder, saved it as my_form_validation.php and autoloaded form_validation

Comment: If you are using google chrome you can press ctrl+shift+i to open the developer console, under the network tab you will be able to see the pages accessed. You will see the request and you need to click that and view the response from the server to see what's going on. Let me know if you get information from that and what it is.

Comment: Also keep in mind this is returning a JSON encoded string that you must parse with jQuery. So you can't just blindly copy and paste this code as it will not work like that.

Comment: The problem is that it will affect all the methods I have in my controller. So it doesn't load any of my methods (login, logout etc). That's why i'm unable to check the request from the network tab. As soon as I remove that json_encode(...) line, all of my methods are working just fine

Comment: Ahh, after I changed my application environment from testing to development, I can now see the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: I just posted a much larger edit that is the full jQuery and full function in a controller I've built and used so it is tested. You just need to modify it to suit your needs. That was an example of using it with jQuery but if it's working without that you should be good to go?

Comment: I'm also coding for PHP 5.5 you may need to use () for arrays instead of [] (:

Comment: ffs, after I removed those square brackets, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW". Right now it looks like this: $this->output->set_output(json_encode('result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array() ));

Comment: $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array() )));

Comment: Yeah, now I got rid of the error, but now another problem comes in. Check my edited post if u may/want to help me a little bit more (:

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head, you could try using individual errors.

In your view:

```
<?php
    $form_errors = array(
        form_error('field_1'),
        form_error('field_2'),
        form_error('field_3'),
        form_error('field_4'),
        form_error('field_5'),
        form_error('field_6')
    );

    $error = FALSE;

    foreach ($form_errors as $form_error)
    {
        if ( ! empty($form_error))
            $error = TRUE;
    }

    if ($error)
        echo "All fields are required".
?>
```

So basically what you are doing here, is filling an array of individual form errors. `form_error()` returns an empty string if the field is filled in correctly according to the validation rule, otherwise it will be an error message.

To confirm that everything is filled in correctly, you are looking for an array of empty strings. If a field isn't filled in correctly, your array will contain an element which has an error message.